# How to hide the points in a combined Line- and BarChart drawn by Chart.js V2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm using the combo-bar-line by Chart.js V2.0 (beta) to show the present Value every 15 min as a Bar-Chart and the maximum from the last day as a Line-Chart (green Line) and the absolute Maximum (red Line)... It works fine - many thanks to nnick and his developer-team for this great work. 
But as you can see the lines have the points which are sensless for me in this case.
[CombinedBar-LineChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLaLP.jpg)

I only need a "flat Line"...
In the Documentation I read that you can set
`point.pointStyle`
or
`point.radius`
but it took no effect yet...

Thank you all for some help :-)
Here comes the Code:

```
    var barChartData = {
        labels: <?php echo $label; ?> ,
        datasets: [{
            type: 'bar',
            label: 'Aktuelle Messung',
            backgroundColor: "#ff9900",
            data: <?php echo $data_1; ?>,
            borderColor: '#ff9900',
            borderWidth: 1
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            label: 'Messung Vortag',
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            data: <?php echo $vsm_vort; ?>,
            borderColor: 'green',
            PointStyle: 'none',
            radius: 0,
            borderWidth: 2
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            label: 'Vereinbartes Maximum',
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            borderColor: 'red',
            data: <?php echo $vsm_max; ?>
        }, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found out, that `point.radius` works very fine... But if you have set `borderWidth` the point will still be displayed in the line.
I changed both values to zero and now I have a "flat line"  ...